# tabs are not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three tabs and on click on tab i want two things to happen one is href link and the other thing is to change the color.
Now both the things are happening but the only problem is the change of color is happening if i click the tab twice.

Here is my code

```
<div class="col-sm-3 text-center sprtr-1">
      <a class="tab-link" id="movies" href="#events?eventType=Movies&industry={{selectedIndustry.name}}" onclick="if(!$('#movies').hasClass('active')){$('#performances').removeClass('active');$('#workshops').removeClass('active');$('#movies').addClass('active');
            }else{return false;}return true;" i18n="EVENT.MOVIES"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></span> MOVIES</a>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 text-center sprtr-1">

      <a class="tab-link" id="performances" href="#events?eventType=Performance&industry={{selectedIndustry.name}}" onclick="if(!$('#performances').hasClass('active')){$('#movies').removeClass('active');$('#workshops').removeClass('active');$('#performances').addClass('active');
            }else{return false;}return true;" i18n="EVENT.PERFORMANCES"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></span> PERFORMANCES</a>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">

      <a class="tab-link" id="workshops" href="#events?eventType=WorkShops&industry={{selectedIndustry.name}}" onclick="if(!$('#workshops').hasClass('active')){$('#movies').removeClass('active');$('#performances').removeClass('active');$('#workshops').addClass('active');
            }else{return false;}return true;" i18n="EVENT.WORKSHOPS"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></span> WORKSHOPS</a>

    </div>
```

I am writing inline code, so someone can help me in this.

Comment: Why not write it in external js? I know this doesn't help with your problem but you should practice to code in external. This isn't internal. This is so-called inline scripting. One thing, It can help you to find the errors easier. And make your code more beautiful.

Comment: i was not able to do that why i did like this is a way to solve this problemm

Answer (score 0):

Actually since you are using *Bootstrap* and it has `events` defines for `:active` and `:focus` etc. for `a` tag all you have to do is to override it also I have remove the inline *jQuery* for a better coding standard and easy to debug in future.

### Code Snippet(with inline jQuery)

```css
a.active,
a.active:active,
a.active:focus {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-3 text-center sprtr-1">
  <a class="tab-link" id="movies" href="#events?eventType=Movies&industry={{selectedIndustry.name}}" onclick="if(!$('#movies').hasClass('active')){$('#performances').removeClass('active');$('#workshops').removeClass('active');$('#movies').addClass('active');
            }else{return false;}return true;" i18n="EVENT.MOVIES"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></span> MOVIES</a>

</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 text-center sprtr-1">

  <a class="tab-link" id="performances" href="#events?eventType=Performance&industry={{selectedIndustry.name}}" onclick="if(!$('#performances').hasClass('active')){$('#movies').removeClass('active');$('#workshops').removeClass('active');$('#performances').addClass('active');
            }else{return false;}return true;" i18n="EVENT.PERFORMANCES"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></span> PERFORMANCES</a>

</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 text-center">

  <a class="tab-link" id="workshops" href="#events?eventType=WorkShops&industry={{selectedIndustry.name}}" onclick="if(!$('#workshops').hasClass('active')){$('#movies').removeClass('active');$('#performances').removeClass('active');$('#workshops').addClass('active');
            }else{return false;}return true;" i18n="EVENT.WORKSHOPS"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></span> WORKSHOPS</a>

</div>
```

### Code Snippet(with outside jQuery)[Recommended]

```js
$('.tab-link').on('click', function() {
  $('.tab-link').removeClass('active');
  if (!($(this).hasClass('active'))) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
a.active,
a.active:active,
a.active:focus {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-3 text-center sprtr-1">
  <a class="tab-link" id="movies" href="#events?eventType=Movies&industry={{selectedIndustry.name}}" i18n="EVENT.MOVIES"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></span> MOVIES</a>

</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 text-center sprtr-1">

  <a class="tab-link" id="performances" href="#events?eventType=Performance&industry={{selectedIndustry.name}}" i18n="EVENT.PERFORMANCES"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></span> PERFORMANCES</a>

</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 text-center">

  <a class="tab-link" id="workshops" href="#events?eventType=WorkShops&industry={{selectedIndustry.name}}" i18n="EVENT.WORKSHOPS"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></span> WORKSHOPS</a>

</div>
```

Comment: i am not able to write the script outside and call so i wrote this inline scripting so u know any this about that please answer

Comment: @raja wait I've updated my answer, but its **strongly recommended to use external jQ**

Comment: hey did u get my question. I am getting the same result as before i have to click twice to make the tab active but i want it on one click

Comment: Have you checked the snippets?  its working on single click!

Comment: Be clear about your environment, which browser are you using as its working perfectly fine on *IE, FF and Chrome*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122189/discussion-between-raja-and-vivekkupadhyay).